# GMail API access from chrome extension? 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have an application that accesses Google APIs out of a Chrome extension via the workflow outlined here.

[Chrome Extensions OAuth Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth)

The basics of the workflow are to initialize the OAuth flow

```
var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
    'request_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
    'authorize_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
    'access_url': 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
    'consumer_key': '{MY_CLIENT_ID}',
    'consumer_secret': '{MY_CLIENT_SECRET}',
    'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/ https://mail.google.com/',
    'app_name': 'Gmail Plugin',
    'callback_page': 'src/google-oauth/chrome_ex_oauth.html'
});
```

Upon installing the extension, the user is taken to dialog page to authenticate and agree to the scopes I ask for. From here I infer that my consumer key and secret are OK. I have allowed access to the GMail, Contacts, and Admin SDK in the Google Developers console.

Prior to this I had requests working with the Contacts API and Admin SDK API. I'm now trying to add some features that utilize the Gmail REST API.

The next step in setting up a request is to make a request from the background page.

```
function getSentEmails() {
  var emailCollection; 
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages";
  var request = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'parameters': {
      'labelIds': 'SENT'
    }
  };
  var callback = function(response, xhr) {
    emailCollection = JSON.parse(response);
    console.dir(emailCollection);
  } 
  oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, callback, request);
};
```

The way the signed requests work is to call a method to complete the next step of the OAuth dance,

```
oauth.authorize(function() {
    getSentEmails();
  });
```

This results in a 403 Forbidden every time. I seem to have no issue accessing the other APIs I mentioned though this OAuth flow. I've allowed the scope in my manifest.json

manifest.json

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "https://mail.google.com/*",
    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/*",
    "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/*",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/*",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify/*",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose/*",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly/*",
    "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken",
    "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken",
    "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken"
  ]
```

I tried an alternate method of building the HTTP request as outlined in the link above.

```
function stringify(parameters) {
  var params = [];
  for(var p in parameters) {
    params.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' +
                encodeURIComponent(parameters[p]));
  }
  return params.join('&');
};
function xhrGetSentEmails() {
    var method = 'GET';
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages';
    var params = {'labelIds': 'SENT'};
    var callback = function(resp, xhr) {
      console.log(resp);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
      callback(xhr, data);
    };
    xhr.open(method, url + '?' + stringify(params), true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', oauth.getAuthorizationHeader(url, method, params));
    xhr.send();
  }
```

I get the same 403 doing this.

I believe I'm authenticating properly though, because if I change

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', oauth.getAuthorizationHeader(url, method, params));
```

to

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','foo' + oauth.getAuthorizationHeader(url, method, params));
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized instead.

Again, no trouble accessing the other APIs I mentioned.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is probably fairly obscure, so I'll share how I ended up resolving it.

I moved my chrome extensions OAuth 2.0 workflow to the newer (since Chrome 29) [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) setup for apps and extensions.

Detailed instructions for setting up OAuth 2.0 for an extension are here.

[Chrome Identity API User Authentication](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity)

Now I can use

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(function(token) {
  // Do HTTP API call with token
});
```

And none of my HTTP requests come up forbidden (403) anymore.

Hope this is helpful to extension builders out there!